# Infinite-dimensional normed spaces and the distance

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

By $X$ we denote an infinite-dimensional normed space (it seems to be obvious that the case of finite dimension is not suitable). Let $X_0$ be a closed subspace of $X$ and $x\in X$. Then there is the distance $d(x,X_0)$ between $x$ and $X_0$ defined as $\inf\{||x-t||:t\in X_0\}$. It is easy to see that $X_0$ is not compact subspace, hence we cannot state that $\exists x_0\in X_0$  $d(x,x_0)=d(x,X_0)$. So, could you help me to build such example?

Comment: $X_0$ is supposed to be closed only. Why should it be compact?

Comment: An example of what? A space where every closed subspace has such an $x_0$? Or a space with a closed subspace $X_0$ with no such best approximation?

Comment: An example of a space $X$, closed subspace $X_0$ and only one point $x\in X_0$

Comment: I mean I just want to get an example when the distance is unreachable

Comment: What is a subspace? Is is linear or just a subset?

Comment: A closed linear subspace

Comment: Is your normed space complete?

Comment: I do not suggest that

Answer (score 6):

Such minimizer exists and is unique if $X$ is uniformly convex and complete. On the other hand, in every non-reflexive Banach space there is a closed hyperplane for which minimizer does not exist, see Theorem 5 in

*James, R. C.*, [**Characterizations of reflexivity**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/sm-23-3-205-216), Stud. Math. 23, 205-216 (1964). [ZBL0113.09303](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0113.09303).

Lastly, in a reflexive Banach space the minimizer always exists but need not be unique.

Comment: It is so general... Well, thank you!

Comment: @Nikita: Then click in the check mark to accept the answer in order to close the question.